# Merging tables in R using multiple fields in left table, one field in right table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes that I'm trying to merge.  The first dataframe (hospital_df) contains a case ID and then a diagnosis codes for diagnosis 1, 2, 3, 4, etc etc.  The second dataframe is a description of each unique diagnosis code, matching the code to a description:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 40, 40, 99, 99, 99, 99)
principal_diagnosis <- c('AA', 'CS', 'AA', 'EG', 'SD', 'DF', 'DD', 'AA', 'DF', 'HG', 'SD')
other_diagnosis <- c('AB', 'CF', 'AD', 'AA', 'SS', 'DS', 'DF', 'AG', 'AB', 'FG', 'VV')
other_diagnosis2 <- c('XX', 'DD', 'SQ', 'SD', 'DF', 'CV', 'DA', 'FD', 'SS', 'WV', 'AA')
hospital_df <- data.frame(id,principal_diagnosis, other_diagnosis, other_diagnosis2)

principal_diagnosis_codes <- c('AA', 'CS', 'AA', 'EG', 'SD', 'DF', 'DD', 'AA', 'DF', 'HG', 'SD', 'AB', 'CF', 'AD', 'SS', 'DS', 'AG', 'FG', 'VV', 'XX', 'SQ', 'CV', 'DA', 'FD', 'WV')
length(principal_diagnosis_codes)
description <- c('disease1',
                 'disease2',
                 'disease3',
                 'disease4',
                 'disease5',
                 'disease6',
                 'disease7',
                 'disease8',
                 'disease9',
                 'disease10',
                 'disease11',
                 'disease12',
                 'disease13',
                 'disease14',
                 'disease15',
                 'disease16',
                 'disease17',
                 'disease18',
                 'disease19',
                 'disease20',
                 'disease21',
                 'disease22',
                 'disease23',
                 'disease24',
                 'disease25')

diagnosis_codes_df <- data.frame(principal_diagnosis_codes, description)
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
ID  principal_diagnosis     other_diagnosis    other_diagnosis2
1   disease1                disease12          disease20
1   disease2                disease13          disease7
5   disease1                disease14          disease21
```

I've tried:

```
    mergedData <- merge(hospital_df, diagnosis_codes_df, by.x=c("principal_diagnosis"),
                        by.y=c("principal_diagnosis_codes"))
    
   mergedData <- merge(mergedData, diagnosis_codes_df, by.x=c("other_diagnosis"),
                        by.y=c("principal_diagnosis_codes"))

mergedData <- merge(mergedData, diagnosis_codes_df, by.x=c("other_diagnosis2"),
                        by.y=c("principal_diagnosis_codes"))
```

But this seems inefficient and also gives me description, description.y, description.x, etc which is slightly confusing. Is there a better way?  I'm a newcomer to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code in Base-R uses the first diagnosis code in the list that matches.

```
hospital_df[-1] <- sapply(unlist(hospital_df[-1]), function(x) diagnosis_codes_df$description[x == diagnosis_codes_df][1])


   id principal_diagnosis other_diagnosis other_diagnosis2
1   1            disease1       disease12        disease20
2   1            disease2       disease13         disease7
3   5            disease1       disease14        disease21
4   5            disease4        disease1         disease5
5   5            disease5       disease15         disease6
6  40            disease6       disease16        disease22
7  40            disease7        disease6        disease23
8  99            disease1       disease17        disease24
9  99            disease6       disease12        disease15
10 99           disease10       disease18        disease25
11 99            disease5       disease19         disease1
```

Comment: Daniel, this worked.  But, I'm still a little unclear on what the code is doing - could you help me understand?  First, of all, why do you need to unlist the dataframe?  Second, what exactly is going on here:   diagnosis_codes_df$description[x == diagnosis_codes_df][1]  ?  Thanks.

Comment: I use `unlist` to combine your 3 columns into one for easier handling. This is later automatically split back into 3 when the reassignment `<-` occurs. For the custom `function(x)` now every element from the combined vector is being passed into the function one at a time as the variable `x`. So the first one for example `x <- "AA"` then. So the function searches for the corresponding description of all diagnosis codes that are `"AA"`. Since there are somtimes more than one, only the first one is take with `[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

We could `deframe` to create a named vector and use that to replace multiple columns in the 'hospital_df' with `mutate/across`.  Here, we use `R 4.0` where `data.frame` `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tibble)
nm1 <- deframe(diagnosis_codes_df)
hospital_df %>% 
    mutate(across(contains('diagnosis'), ~ nm1[.x]))
#    id principal_diagnosis other_diagnosis other_diagnosis2
#1   1            disease1       disease12        disease20
#2   1            disease2       disease13         disease7
#3   5            disease1       disease14        disease21
#4   5            disease4        disease1         disease5
#5   5            disease5       disease15         disease6
#6  40            disease6       disease16        disease22
#7  40            disease7        disease6        disease23
#8  99            disease1       disease17        disease24
#9  99            disease6       disease12        disease15
#10 99           disease10       disease18        disease25
#11 99            disease5       disease19         disease1
```

---

Or using `base R`, construct a named vector ('nm1'), loop over the 'diagnosis' columns of 'hospital_df' (`lapply`), use the named vector to match and replace the values, and assign it back to the columns of the dataset

```
nm1 <- with(diagnosis_codes_df, setNames(description, principal_diagnosis_codes))
hospital_df[-1] <- lapply(hospital_df[-1], function(x) nm1[x])
```

Or convert to `matrix` and then do a match

```
hospital_df[-1] <-  nm1[as.matrix(hospital_df[-1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` :

```
library(dplyr)

hospital_df %>% mutate(across(-1,~diagnosis_codes_df$description[
                match(.x, diagnosis_codes_df$principal_diagnosis_codes)])) 



#   id principal_diagnosis other_diagnosis other_diagnosis2
#1   1            disease1       disease12        disease20
#2   1            disease2       disease13         disease7
#3   5            disease1       disease14        disease21
#4   5            disease4        disease1         diseases
#5   5            disease5       disease15         disease6
#6  40            disease6       disease16        disease22
#7  40            disease7        disease6        disease23
#8  99            disease1       disease17        disease24
#9  99            disease6       disease12        disease15
#10 99           disease10       disease18        disease25
#11 99            disease5       disease19         disease1
```

Same using base R :

```
hospital_df[-1] <- lapply(hospital_df[-1], function(x) 
            diagnosis_codes_df$description[match(x, 
            diagnosis_codes_df$principal_diagnosis_codes)])
```